# Dynamic portfolio rebalancing Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i am facing a problem with my data. I'm stuck since two days.

I want to calculate an annual return of my portfolio on a daily basis by using todays value and the next 251 values. 
    I should do this calculation on a daily basis to create a time-series of returns.

```
e.g. Calculation 1: Day 1 + following 251 values
Calculation 2: Day 2 + following 251 values
Calculation 3: Day 3 + following 251

I tried to develop the dynamic structure of the calculation, but I failed.
Is it possible for some of you guys to come up with some ideas? 

Highly appreciate! 

# Starting at 18-03-2008, we compute the optimal annual weights an         
returns of our portfolio, day-by-day

DowJones['Number'] = range(1, 1711)

i = 1

while i < 1458:

DJ30=DowJones[DowJones['Number']< i+253]`
DJ30.iloc[1:]`
i=i+1`
DJ30.iloc[1]`
DJ30 = DJ30.iloc[i:]` 
DJ30 = DJ30.set_index('Date')`
returns = DJ30.pct_change()`
```

Comment: It is very hard to give a proper answer without more data, but you should look into rolling. What about `df[column].rolling(251).sum()`. Then if you want to go forward you either shift the data using `shift` or sort the df in reverse before running rolling sum.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it. If you send me a mail herbert7854@t-online.de I can provide more date

Comment: I have 1710 dates, starting with 2008-03-19. The first calculation includes 2008-03-19 - 2009-03-18. The next one should include 2008-03-20 - 2009-03-19

Answer (score 1):

To get the sum om the next 251 values: Sort, roll, sum:

```
df['one_year_sum'] = df.sort_values(by=['datetime'],ascending=False)['data'].rolling(251).sum()
```

Edit after comment:

```
df['Number'].pct_change(251) # Or -251
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is not the perfect solution, as I don't want to calculate the value of the next 251 value, I just want to add one new value and drop the oldest one